# Importing CSV to datatable with SQL command, values over 5,000,000,000 are left out / blank

Tags: sql, csv, import, datatable

I have a .CSV file that im filling a datatable in my application with.
one of the cells is a number, for example: 5720358152
these values seem to be getting skipped and nothing is put into the datatable.

here is my code:

```
Dim csvFile As String = "I:\STOCK.csv"
        Dim folder = "I:\"

        Dim csvStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
        
Dim csvSQL = "SELECT * FROM [STOCK.csv]" 

        Dim MyDT As DataTable
        Using csvCn = New OleDbConnection(csvStr),
         cmd As New OleDbCommand(csvSQL, csvCn)

            Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                MyDT = New DataTable
                da.Fill(MyDT)
            End Using
        End Using

        StockTakeDGV.DataSource = MyDT
```

Here is a list of numbers that get left out.

```
5720358152
5720358150
5720358146
5720350121
5720324303
5720308119
5720308118
5720308115
5720308114
5720308110
5720308104
```

But these numbers are fine:

```
4021021135
4021021132
4021021126
1320203187
1320023154
```

at first i thought it might have been the number of digits but other numbers with this many digits work, but i assume it's more to do with the "type" of number and that the value exceeds the limitation of that number type.

how do i overcome this problem?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Which is the column data type? For example In Postgresql Interger range is from -2147483648 to +2147483647, so you would be out of range.

Comment: To be honest i have no idea, what your asking with, Which DBMS are you using? Which is the column data type? i only know that my above code works, so i use it.

Comment: i would be happy to treat the numbers as if they were just text. but i don't know how to tell the OleDB connection to set specific columns to specific data types.

Comment: Hello, what type of database are you using (sql server, mysql, postgres)? What type of column are you trying to import the data(string,int,bigint)?

Comment: I mean the database you are using (where you wanto to insert the data from the csv file, and the data type of the table column where you want to import the numbers. Ok

Comment: You specified the table columns data type when you create the table.

Comment: oh um just temp storing it in a "datatable" in ram, before its written to a MDB file. 
``` 
  MyDT = New DataTable
                da.Fill(MyDT)
```

Comment: Microsoft Access Long Integer (Default) stores numbers from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (no fractions). You should use Large Number data type instead (exist in new Microsoft Office versions).

Comment: @nachospiu how do i set the datatype? will i need to create the table, and specify the headers and the types for all columns first before i fill the datatable?

Comment: I don't know, but I will try to put the numbers between quotes (in csv file) to see if they will be process as string and it resolved your problem. Make a copy of the csv file first to backup.